# Creating my own theme for an app

Tags: android, customization, android-theme

I have been searching Stack Overflow for an answer for this but couldn't find. I have an app and I want to change it to a theme from inside the app as user prefers. Also in my app, I have created all my custom buttons and other images. I want to make another set of images so that when the user changes the theme, these images come accordingly. As of now I have Appcompact theme and on top of it the images i created are processed when the app is opened. I hope you undertandd my question.

Answer (score -1):

Well, my advice is to take it a step by step flow, understand themes and styles and how they work, how you target different APIs, different languages, LTR and RTL and so on, then use a simple online tool to create the work for you, and last but not least, how to change the theme within the App.

Follow Derek's tutorial to introduce yourself to themes and styles on http://www.newthinktank.com/2014/07/make-android-apps-9/

you can then use this simple tool to create your custom theme (which you can import into your project) and use to assign activities' XML android:style part of elements :

http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/

I wouldn't change each and every element style on users' choice, this will result in a complex code and a performance degradation. I would suggest starting this by having two themes, intro screen, settings activity, and two "main" activities, per settings the user set, you can tell your intro which activity to load, where each activity has a theme set in its layout resource. Keep in mind to move out your code logic outside the activity Class, so you don't have a copy-code state in your app (use outer classes and import them).